# Matrix operation (simplify)

Tags: matrix

I had a $6\times 6$ matrix

```
{{1., 0., 0., 0., 0, 0},
 {0, 0.538752, 0.382352, 0.0788956, 2.35142*10^-7, 0}, 
 {0, 0.121876, 0.449018, 0.405176, 0.0239311, 0},
 {0, 0.0147839, 0.264751, 0.596752, 0.123713, 0},
 {0, 0, 0.0294091, 0.381909, 0.563762, 0.0249205},
 {0, 0, 0., 0., 0., 1.}}
```

and I wanted to multiply row 3 by 0.8, row 4 by 1.2 and divide each column by the sum of each column except the first and last column.

Instead of doing it manually by editing it on the matrix, is there an alternative or *Mathematica* code to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operation on `m` itself:

```
m[[{3, 4}]] *= {.8, 1.2};

m[[All, 2 ;; -2]] = Transpose[Normalize[#, Total] & /@ Transpose[m[[All, 2 ;; -2]]]];

m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

after a talk, if you want to normalize (with Total norm) rows then skip transposing:

```
m[[2 ;; -2]] = Normalize[#, Total] & /@ m[[2 ;; -2]];
```

and if you don't want to modify `m` you can do:

```
Fold[
 MapAt[#2[[1]], #, #2[[2]]] &,
 m,
 {{.8 # &, 3},
  {1.2 # &, 4},
  {Normalize[#, Total] &, 2 ;; -2}
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Where you reading my mind? :) I think you posted 5 seconds before me, so I will delete my post. good answer.

Comment: @Nasser oh, it seems so :) Sorry and thanks :)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the confusing question. What i really mean is that each column is divided by to sum of its column. For example, Sum of column 2 is 1.22756, so each element of column 2 is divided by 1.22756. Same goes to column 3, 4, 5.
As the sum of first and last column is 1, 1/1 is still 1.

Comment: After divide, the sum of each column should give value of 1.

Comment: @KeithLim Sum for 2nd column is `0.675412` after multiplications of rows. But at the end it is `1` you can check by `m[[All, 2]] // Total`. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Kuba I think you had misunderstand my question. Supposingly the sum of column is to be 1, not the row.
For instance, column 3: 0.149085+0.329955*0.8+0.215943*1.2+0.026177=x
then each of the elements in column 3 is to be divided by x:
(0.149085/x  0.329955*0.8/x  0.215943*1.2/x  0.026177)

Comment: @KeithLim Take a look at the picture, columns 2nd to 5th are summing up to 1 each. Not rows. I still don't understand what is the problem, sorry.

Comment: @KeithLim Moreover, where do you have those number from? "column 3: 0.149085.." this is not in the matrix you have given,

Comment: MY apologies!!! I've confused with row and columns. What i really want is the sum of rows to be 1. Not columns. (facepalm x10)

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1., 0., 0., 0., 0, 0}, {0, 0.538752, 0.382352, 0.0788956, 
    2.35142*10^-7, 0}, {0, 0.121876, 0.449018, 0.405176, 0.0239311, 
    0}, {0, 0.0147839, 0.264751, 0.596752, 0.123713, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0.0294091, 0.381909, 0.563762, 0.0249205}, {0, 0, 0., 0., 0., 
    1.}};  
list2 = {1, 1, 0.8, 1.2, 1, 1} list;
Transpose[MapAt[#/Total[#] &, Transpose[list2], {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}]]
(*{{1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0, 0.823788, 0.351208, 0.0525604, 
  3.21512*10^-7, 0}, {0., 0.149085, 0.329955, 0.215943, 0.026177, 
  0.}, {0., 0.0271267, 0.291823, 0.477068, 0.202985, 0.}, {0, 0., 
  0.0270136, 0.254428, 0.770838, 0.0249205}, {0, 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.}}*)
```